# Quicker way to calculate geographic distance between two points

Tags: java, optimization, geolocation, gps, gis

I borrowed the following method from somewhere on the internet (Can't remember where). But its doing a straight forward process, finding the distance between two gps points. It works just fine, except that it may be a little slow, as I'm running it across millions of points. 
I was wondering if anyone knows an approach that would be computationally less expensive.

The accuracy needs to be in the general area of 'correct' but doesn't need to be 100% accurate.

```
private double distFrom(double lat1, double lng1, double lat2, double lng2) {
    double earthRadius = 3958.75;
    double dLat = Math.toRadians(lat2-lat1);
    double dLng = Math.toRadians(lng2-lng1);
    double a = Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) +
           Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat1)) * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat2)) *
           Math.sin(dLng/2) * Math.sin(dLng/2);
    double c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a));
    return   earthRadius * c;
  }
}
```

P.s I did indeed find a number of other relevant questions, but they don't really focus on my speed concern.

Comment: What are you using the distances for? A typical use for this is to find all X's close to Y.  If this applies to you, then you should consider using a bounding box approach which may limit your calculations from millions to just a couple dozen.  For example, find me the closest grocery store within 5 miles.  You wouldn't need to calculate the distance from my house to a store in California or Alaska.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you don't mind ignoring the slight oblateness of the Earth (and your posted Haversine code does just that anyway) consider pre-converting all of your spherical (lat/long) coordinates into 3D **unit-length** cartesian coordinates first, per:

> http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system

Then your spherical distance between cartesian coordinates `p1` and `p2` is simply:

```
r * acos(p1 . p2)
```

Since `p1` and `p2` will have unit length this reduces to four multiplications, two additions and one inverse trig operation per pair.

Also note that the calculation of dot products is an ideal candidate for optimisation, e.g. via GPU, MMX extensions, vector libraries, etc.

Furthermore, if your intent is to *order* the pairs by distance, potentially ignoring more distant pairs, you can defer the expensive `r*acos()` part of the equation by sorting the list just on the dot product value since for all valid inputs (i.e. the range `[-1, 1]`) it's guaranteed that:

```
acos(x) < acos(y) if x > y
```

You then just take the `acos()` of the values you're actually interested in.

Re: the potential inaccuracies with using `acos()`, those are really only significant if you're using single-precision `float` variables.  Using a `double` with 16 significant digits should get you distances accurate to within one metre or less.

Answer (score 1):

That's the haversine algorithm, will provide you with a decent level of accuracy.

If it really is "millions" of points, perhaps implement a cache of calculations that you've made...  if you come across a pair of coordinates, both of which are sufficiently close to a pair whose distance you've already calculated, then use the cached value?

Or try to cache some of the intermediate steps, e.g. degree to radians conversions.

Comment: Yup I'd say caching could help, right now its quite a lazy approach. Didn't think the dataset would get this large!

Answer (score 1):

If you sacrifice accuracy there are some improvements you can make. As far as I remember, `sin(x)` is [approximately](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small-angle_approximation) equal to `x` for small `x`. Also it looks like you are computing the same things several times, like: `Math.sin(dLat/2)` (which can actually be approximated to `dLat/2` as stated above).

However if you are doing millions of these operations, I would somewhere else.

- Is your algorithm optimal? Maybe you are doing too many simple computations?
- If points come from database, can you perform the computations as stored procedures on the database server side?
- If you are looking for closest points, can you index them somehow?
- Can geospatial indexes help you?

Comment: I'm not using any form of GIS extensions in the DB. Would that make a major difference?

Comment: @steve That could potentially make a difference, however I am not sure how big. If your points are in a spatially enabled database you could let the database do the distance calculation. But that is a bit outside the scope of your question (how to do in java).

Comment: Adding a db isnt' an issue, as long as I have something I can point java to which gets me a distance number back that would be fine :)

Answer (score 1):

You might try the law of cosines for spherical trigonometry:

```
a = sin(lat1) * sin(lat2)
b = cos(lat1) * cos(lat2) * cos(lon2 - lon1)
c = arccos(a + b)
d = R * c
```

But it **will** be inaccurate for short distances (and probably just marginally faster).

There is a complete discussion [here](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/gis-faq-5.1.html).
However, the haversine formula is the most correct way, so aside from what others have suggested there may not be much you can do.
<del>@Alnitak's answer may work, but spherical to Cartesian conversions are not necessarily fast.</del>

Comment: it only takes four trig ops (or two trig, 2 muls, 2 subtract and 2 sqrts) to convert from spherical to polar, and the point of my answer is that you only need to do that once _per point_, not for every combination of pairs.

Comment: Thanks! I'm particularly interested in areas with a short distance so perhaps its not optimal. I'll run it and see how it looks though!

Comment: The downside of Haversine is that the intermediate calculations rely on differences between angles, so it _has_ to be worked out for each pair.  The problem metioned in the link with arccos (used both here and in my answer) shouldn't matter if you use `double` variables with 16 digits of precision.