# Calculating geographical distance using algorithm based on dot product of Cartesian coordinates

Tags: java, algorithm, math, geo

I would like to calculate the distance between two geographical points (defined by latitude and longitude pair) using the solution described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6409253/4549619).

Even though I understand the general concept the part with *pre-converting all of your spherical (lat/long) coordinates into 3D unit-length cartesian coordinates first* is problematic for me.

Could someone explain the algorithm that needs to we written to achieve the above? Java would be perfect, but pseudocode will do as well.

Update: I'm not interested in Haversine method.

Comment: While not exactly a duplicate, I think you would be interested in this question and its answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3694380/calculating-distance-between-two-points-using-latitude-longitude-what-am-i-doi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's start with transformation to spherical coordinates. Observe that latitude/longitude is almost the same as angles in spherical coordinates. The only difference is that unlike `phi` latitude starts not from the North pole, but from the equator.

[image]

So, if you have latitude equal to +90 (90° N) corresponding phi angle is 0°, and when latitude equal to -90 (90° S) corresponding `phi` angle is 180°.

```
phi   = -latitude + 90°
theta =  longitude
rho   = 1
```

Now, you can go to Cartesian:

[image: x=rho*sin(theta)*cos(phi); y = rho*sin(theta)*sin(phi); z = rho*cos(theta);]

But in your case `rho = 1`, so

```
x = sin(theta)*cos(phi);
y = sin(theta)*sin(phi);
z = cos(theta);
```

where `phi` and `theta` are defined as above.